# Send Mail with Large Attachment using c#

Tags: c#, email, .net-3.5, email-attachments

I am trying to send email using Smtp using "smtp.gmail.com". Our project use .net 3.5 Framweork and c# to keep XP Compatibility. However, I always failed when the attachment is over 5MB. I read that google smtp allow to send attachment as large as 25MB. However, when I try to do it, it always throw error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.send(IntPtr socketHandle, Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Base64Stream.FlushInternal()
   at System.Net.Base64Stream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimePart.Send(BaseWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Mime.MimeMultiPart.Send(BaseWriter writer)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

This is the method I use to send mail:

```
public void Send( SMTPServerInfo serverInfo, string from, string to, string subject, string body, IList<Attachment> attachments )
{
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  client.EnableSsl = serverInfo.EnableSSL;
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage( from, to, subject, body );
  if( IsHTML )
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
  client.Host = serverInfo.ServerName;
  if( !Text.IsEmpty( serverInfo.UserName ) )
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( serverInfo.UserName, serverInfo.Password );
  if( serverInfo.Port.HasValue )
    client.Port = serverInfo.Port.Value;
  if( attachments != null )
    foreach( Attachment attachment in attachments )
      message.Attachments.Add( attachment );

  client.Send( message );
  message.Dispose();
}
```

I am not sure why is this happening.

Comment: What is the inner exception message?

Comment: I have tested your code with GMX mail server and it works just fine. I have compiled it with .NET 3.5 and sent 8.53 MB file - no errors. I assume that it might be GMail restriction. (might be somehow adjustable in account settings?)

Comment: @ChrisBint I update the inner exception stack trace.

Comment: SmtpClient instance has a default timeout period of 100 seconds ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)). Try increasing this timeout period (`client.Timeout`) so that it has enough time to upload your attachment. See if it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error thrown when the SMTP is force to stop when sending large attachment. The problem is not within the SMTP neither the Timeout. See:

```
 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted
```

That is the reason the error shown. The thread that sending the email is aborted. See we might need to check more on the Thread problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Instantiate the mail like this:

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment1;
 attachment1 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(attachmentFilePath_Here);
 message.Attachments.Add(attachment1);
```

Comment: The issue is not with adding the attachments, it is the size of them, how will the above help with that?